# How to remove the "None" when I finding the meta content by BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup to get the meta content from a website. However, when I print the meta data, it always followed by "None" at the end. How can I remove the "None" and only get the data I need? Here is my code and the output. Many Thanks.

```
url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
    if tag.get("name", None) == "price":
    print (tag.get("content", None))

Output:
153.92
None
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `print` statement after `if tag.get("name", None) == "price":` this line check one more condition `if` `content` exists or not. Because of you are printing `None` `if` `content` key not in `tag`.

```
for tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
    if tag.get("name", None) == "price":
        if tag.get("content", None): # check this if it is not None
            print(tag.get("content"))
```